# Função insereConta não está funcionando

Tags: php, pdo

Tenho a seguinte classe em php:

```
<?php
class contaEntrada {

public $mostraDados;
public $insereDados;

function conectar(){
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    $dbname = "fluxo_de_caixa";

    try {
        $opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fluxo_de_caixa;", "root", "root", $opcoes);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $pdo;
}

function insereConta($id_empresa, $cat, $subcat, $val, $forPag, $data){
    $pdo = conectar();
    $val = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $val)));

    if($data == ''){
        $data = date("Y-m-d");
    }

    $this->insereDados->$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO entrada (id_entrada, id_empresa, categoria, subcategoria, valor, forma_pagamento, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $this->insereDados->bindValue(1, NULL);
    $this->insereDados->bindValue(2, $id_empresa);
    $this->insereDados->bindValue(3, $cat);
    $this->insereDados->bindValue(4, $subcat);
    $this->insereDados->bindValue(5, $val);
    $this->insereDados->bindValue(6, $forPag);
    $this->insereDados->bindValue(7, $data);
    $this->insereDados->execute();
}
<?
```

Depois, chamo a classe e a função:

```
<?php
require_once "con/conexao.php";
require_once "classes/contaEntrada.php";

$entrada = new contaEntrada();

$id_empresa = 1;
$cat = 1;
$subcat = 1;
$val = "100,00";
$forPag = "Blablabla";
$data;

$entrada->insereConta($id_empresa, $cat, $subcat, $val, $forPag, $data);
?>
```

Porém, quando executo a função, aparece a mensagem "SERVER ERROR   500" na tela.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Na função insereconta no final tem um `<?` é erro de digitação? erro 500 ou tela em branco sempre é erro de programação. Ative os erros, dessa forma, adicione essas duas linhas do no início do arquivo, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Tem outras dicas no [wiki do php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) além dessa.

Comment: Esse <? é erro de digitação mesmo, pois não coloquei no código.
Vou colocar essa linha para exibir erros.

Comment: Agora aparecem esse dois aviso de erro:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/sistemas_web/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_v_hap/classes/contaEntrada.php on line 31

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/sistemas_web/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_v_hap/classes/contaEntrada.php on line 31

Comment: `$insereDados` faz o que? tem a conexão?

Comment: Sim, veja no código acima.
Caso não seja isso que você está perguntando, desculpa, então não entendi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$insereDados` não parece ter uma propriedade chamada `pdo` nem a conexão, quem recebe a conexão é a variável `$pdo` ela é quem deve chamar `prepare()`

```
 $this->insereDados->$pdo->prepare("INSERT ....")
```

Modifique o código para:

```
$pdo = conectar();
//código omitido
$this->insereDados = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ....");

$this->insereDados->bindValue(1, NULL);
$this->insereDados->bindValue(2, $id_empresa);
//demais binds ...

if(!$this->insereDados->execute()){
   print_r($this->insereDados->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Beleza, acho que era isso mesmo.

Comment: Era isso mesmo @rray. Eu tinha trocado o "=" por "->"

Comment: Pra que serve esse:

if(!$this->insereDados->execute()){
   print_r($this->insereDados->errorInfo());
}

Comment: Vai imprimir a mensagem de erro, se acontecer um. @GustavoSevero

Comment: E como faço para exibir uma mensagem de sucesso ou falha, nessa execução?

Comment: @GustavoSevero como está usando exceptions coloca o `execute()` dento do  `try-catch` ele vai capturar uma PDOException la você pode fazer o tratamento, do contrario é sucesso.

Comment: OK, vou fazer isso. Valeu